# Calculate age in days from date of birth

Tags: python, date

How to calculate age in days starting from the date of birth to today. For example, the date of birth is **1990, 7, 25**, I would like to check the number of total days from the date of birth to today.

Comment: General pointers: `time.strptime()` and `time.time()` will help you here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use `date` from `datetime` package to check the number of days by first getting today's date `date.today` and subtracting with your date of birth.

```
from datetime import date    
age = date.today()-date(1990,7,25)
print(age.days)
```

Comment: Might be good to mention that the result is a `timedelta`.

Comment: import datetime

day = int(input("day[1,2,3,..31]: "))
month = int(input("Month[1,2,3,...12]: "))
year = int(input("year[0~2020]: "))
birth_day = datetime.date(year, month, day)
age = date.today() - birth_day
print(age.days)

Answer (score 1):

you can do using `datetime` module.

```
>>> (datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.datetime(1990,7,25)).days
9455
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **datetime** in the python standard module, you can simply **subtract** the current datetime and birthday datetime together.

```
from datetime import date
age = datetime.today() - birthday
print age.days
```